# The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Cannot create process, error code: 998)

Tags: java, json, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am trying to run java through VS code version 15.I have my jdk 13 installed but when I try to compile or run the program error pops up:

```
"The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Cannot create process, error code: 998)."
```

and after that another window with error shows up. It says:
`JAVA.UTIL.CONCURRENT.TIMEOUTEXCEPTION:TIMEOUT`.

Maybe there is something wrong with `launch.json`, but I don t know what.

Comment: „*…when i try to compile or run the peogram error pops up…*“ — Do you feel like showing us the program? TIA.

Comment: Does this exception happen for all projects or the current one?